# How can I configure LibreELEC to work with a PIFI DAC+ v2.0 HiFi board?

Tags: openelec, i2s

The PIFI DAC+ board is mounted on a RPi 3, but when trying to configure the audio output device in LibreELEC, I cannot see an option to select the I2S DAC board.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This board can be configured just like the HiFiBerry DAC+.

First mount the `/flash` as writable:

```
mount -o remount,rw /flash
```

Then edit the `/flash/config.txt` file and add the following lines:

```
dtparam=i2s=on
dtoverlay=hifiberry-dacplus
```

Reboot and you should now see a new audio output device listed in LibreELEC.